# Thread-safety of preallocated unordered_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, unordered-map

In a case where you know exactly the maximum number of elements your unordered map will ever contain, and you preallocate that exact number of buckets.

**What operations are thread-safe on that container (not the objects stored in the container)?**

Comment: typically STL containers are safe for multiple readers, but not multiple writers.

Comment: I think (almost) all reads with no writes to the same read locations at the same time are safe, just like the other containers.

Comment: So preallocating the buckets gives no additional level of thread-safety? (I was anticipating this may be the answer, but was hoping not ..)

Comment: exact number of buckets? Do you really think if there are 100 elements in a hash map that map uses exactly 100 buckets?

Comment: @Doug T, also Mark Garcia, can you reference some specification/documentation for that?  You've got "typically" and "almost" in your comments, and in reality it's always the atypical and hardly-ever branch in the code that blows up one time in a million :)

Comment: @wilsonmichaelpatrick I say "typically" because before C++11 this was vendor specific, but that rule generally held. I'm not sure if C++11 has put this guarantee in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it does not seem you fully understand how a hash map aka unordered_map works. You can read [this article on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to better understand it. So if you do not mean 
that you have [minimal perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function) then setting amount of buckets exactly the same as expected count of elements will make things worse. If you do expect to have minimal perfect hash function, this is a very special case and you should mention that in question and probably how you are going achieve that.

Anyway I doubt you would get any formal thread safety guarantee on operations of unordered_map even if you would provide minimal perfect hash function.

Comment: The intention isn't to improve performance or perfect hashing, but to prevent the container being rehashed and therefore the elements moving around.

Comment: You should read and understand that article. For hash map to split n object in n buckets evenly you have to have minimal perfect hash function. Otherwise you cannot easily predict how many buckets your n objects will use, and your question is meaningless - setting amount of buckets to particular value does not affect thread safety.